# An extension of Kato's Selection Theorem?

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-analysis, functional-analysis

One formulation of the well-known Kato Selection Theorem states that, given an analytic family of $n \times n$ complex, *symmetric* matrices $M(t)$, one can choose an orthonormal basis $\{e_i(t)\}_{i = 1, \ldots, n}$ and functions $\{\lambda_i(t)\}_{i = 1, \ldots, n}$, both depending analytically on $t$, such that
$$M(t)e_i(t) = \lambda_i(t)e_i(t),~~i = 1, \ldots, n.$$

In all statements I've encountered, the parameter $t$ comes from an open subset of $\mathbb{C}$ or maybe $\mathbb{R}$. I would like to know if the following generalization of this theorem to infinite dimensions still holds:

For any **smooth** family of $n \times n$ complex matrices (not necessarily symmetric) $M(x)$, where $x$ comes from a **Hilbert space**, one can find a basis $\{e_i(x)\}_{i = 1, \ldots, n}$, depending smoothly on $x$, such that $M(x)$ is **upper triangular** when written in the basis $\{e_i(x)\}_{i = 1, \ldots, n}$.

The conclusion is weaker because I don't care about eigenvalues, just the upper triangular form, but now things are only smooth.

I would still be interested if the above theorem holds in the analytic category.

Thank you!